# My Balloon stop moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Combine codes without affect my footer:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {  

    moveUp(); 

function moveDown() {
        $('#Balloon').animate({'marginTop' : "+=300px"}, 3000,moveUp)
        }
         function moveUp(){
        $('#Balloon').animate({'marginTop' : "-=300px"}, 3000,moveDown)
        }          });

    var $scrollingDiv = $("#Balloon");
          $(window).scroll(function(){                        $scrollingDiv
              .stop()
              .animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow" );

});


</script>
```

My Balloon floated up/down at 1st, but it stop moving completely when scrolled up/down the page.

Need professional advice? 
1) How to make Balloon continues moving when scroll up/down page? 
2) Can I add more effect of CSS codes, where to put?

Comment: Can u post ur code in fiddle? Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/496x4wxy/4/    but Balloon not moving at all when loaded. see pic below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `moveUp` function when scroll function is completed.

```
$scrollingDiv.stop().animate({"marginTop": ($(window).scrollTop() + 30) + "px"}, "slow" ,moveUp);
```

Pay attention to `,moveUp);` section after `"slow"`.

**[Check This JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/496x4wxy/)**

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/496x4wxy/4/ but Balloon not moving at all when loaded. see pic below

Comment: Balloon not moving at all? i can see that balloon move up and down both in my fiddle and in your fiddle!

Comment: That's funny thing work well in fiddle, but different from blogger. Only move when removed the .stop() but it affect my footer (open gap underneath when the balloon move Down!)

Comment: You should simulate your problem and create a fiddle, i think you ask your question in a poor way. first you say `it stop moving completely when scrolled up/down` and then `not moving at all Only move when removed the .stop() in blogger` without any mention or tag about blogger.

Comment: I (newbie!) Separated windows in fiddle, quite confusing. Always see parts parts on crap sites, not sure where to put!

Why no complete codes blended together? Can a Animation codes all put in 1 side like my pic below?

Not every codes blended can run in fiddle guarantee can work in Blogger. Answer: Not compatible, or Glitch!

But your code amended (add 'moveUp' function one) same as removed the .stop() 
(Now working!)

But both methods, the balloon bypass underneath the footer open big gap! Till can scrolling down....  

Any solution to fix it, stop at a certain height?